# Alert if number of Processes falls less than 5

Tags: powershell

I'm needing to monitor the processes running on a server that are named "Prov.Messenger.exe" and alert if the number of occurrences is less than 5.

I know I can look at PowerShell with the Get-Process command, which I've done a "get-process prov*" at a Power Shell Command prompt and it shows 5 which is correct.

How can I get some functionality to check if the number of occurrences is less than 5 then alert though? I'm needing to do this from a remote server.

Comment: If you want to send an email alert, use Send-MailMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
if ($(Get-Process "prov*").count -lt 5) {
  # Alert logic
}
```

If you need this to run continuously, wrap the above block in a while loop and add a sleep command

Comment: Thanks very much for that, is it possible to use get-process against a remote server though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner for monitoring processes remotely:

```
Get-Process -ComputerName MyPC
```